# Can the compiler assign the generic return type by knowing to which type I assign the value?

Tags: c#, generics

I am wondering if I can make it so that I can omit the generic type of the call when I make it clear what type I am expecting.

In this example you see the function barFun which has a generic return type. I call the function and assign the value to a bool variable. Can I now somehow allow myself to not provide the generic type?

```
public void fooFun()
{
    bool guessTheType = barFun();
}

private T barFun<T>()
{
    List<Object> objects = new List<Object>();
    objects.Add(2);
    objects.Add("a");
    objects.Add(true);

    foreach (var obj in objects)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(T))
        {
            return (T)obj;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: No, the generic parameters can only be inferred for method parameters, not for return values.

Comment: Yes, by adding a method parameter which has type `T`

Comment: Since you have no method parameters, the arguments of which could be used to infer the type parameter, you'll have to do `var guessTheType = barFun<bool>();`

Comment: Yes, that's what I was afraid, will be the answer. Thanks for all your confirmations!

Comment: I don't think C# can even deal with co-variant return types. There are languages that safely do what you describe, but not C#.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns not sure why it's relevant though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `out` parameter, but it's a bit weird.

```cs
private void barFun<T>(out T ret)
{

//
    ret = objects.OfType<T>().First();
}
```

Then

```cs
barFun(out bool guessTheType);

// or

bool guessTheType;

barFun(out guessTheType);
```

Note that you can just use LINQ instead of the `foreach`

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't work that way. Types can not be inferred by guessing what type you expect. There is just too many uncertainties, that guessing would do any good. You don't want a compiler to guess. It's called computer science for a reason.

What you could do is this:

```
var guessTheType = barFun<bool>();
```

There is no guessing obviously.